# How do you configure SWFUpload to work with an ASP.NET C# WebService?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use SWFUpload with an ASP.NET Web Forms project. I need to get at Request.Files[0] But I can't do that in my WebService!

Anyone know a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell SWFUpload is a JS/Flash front-end control that is designed to work with a form, NOT a web service.  My guess is that if you need to in the end send the file to a web service you will need an intermediate page to take the upload and submit to the service.